# WHILE statement which requires multiple lines of code for conditional

Tags: php

The following receives a proposed username, and returns the username if not used, or the username appended by the smallest integer if used. It works fine, but I just can't help wondering if it could be done just as well with a single method.  What's got me stumped is the WHILE statement requires both `$stmt->execute(...)` and `return $stmt->fetchColumn()` as the conditional.  I guess an anonymous function would work, but don't think this will allow the prepared statement to be used for each call.  I am thinking a DO loop might work, but I don't have much experience with them and reading http://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.do.while.php implies I should "use goto operator instead of this hack."  Please provide recommended way of doing this.  Thanks

```
<?php
    class myClass
    {
        public function createUsername($name)
        {
            $i='';
            while($this->openUsername($name.$i)==FALSE){$i=$i+1;}
            return $name.$i;
        }
        private function openUsername($name)
        {
            $sql='SELECT id FROM users WHERE username=?';
            try
            {
                $stmt = db::db()->prepare($sql);
                $stmt->execute(array($name));
                return $stmt->fetchColumn()?FALSE:TRUE;
            }
            catch(PDOException $e){die(library::sql_error($e,$sql));}
        }

    }
?>
```

Comment: Using two methods is actually better, it makes the code more readable and the single methods less complex.

Comment: @fab.  Any way to use the same prepared statement instead of recreating it each time the second method is called?  Not that I am really concerned about the extra time, just curious.  Thanks!

Comment: yes, store `$stmt` as a private property and only prepare it if it does not exist yet (i would move this check into a `getUserNameStatement()` method)

Comment: They way you have it set works well, and is the best implementation that I can think of for it, though I would make the modification of making `$i` random if the username is found.  Or, the option of changing the SQL to `SELECT username FROM users WHERE username LIKE CONCAT(?, '%')` to return all premutations of the username that already exist, and then pull the integer off of it to do the '+1' to.  But while checking that, you'd also have to make sure that the username being pass exists in the return with `$name == $row['username']` type of thing.

Comment: That would add more code, but with a large user-base, would significantly decrease the SQL queries required to find a working username.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't know if this will work, and please vote it down (but please give comment why) if you think it is not a good way of doing it.  Thanks

```
public function createUsername($name)
{
    try
    {
        $i='';
        $sql='SELECT id FROM users WHERE username=?';
        $stmt = db::db()->prepare($sql);
        do {
            $stmt->execute(array($name.$i));
            $used=$stmt->fetchColumn()?TRUE:FALSE;
            if(!$used) {$i=$i+1;}
        } while ($used);
    }
    catch(PDOException $e){die(library::sql_error($e,$sql));}
    return $name.$i;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Personally I'd do this:

```
function createUsername($name) {
    // validate $name, for instance restrict to alphanumeric characters with preg_match
    $sql = "SELECT GREATEST(`username`) AS `out` FROM `users` 
         WHERE `username` REGEXP '^".$name."\d*$'";
    $result = // whatever code it takes for PDO to run the above query
    if( !$result) return $name; // nobody with that name yet
    $number = preg_replace("^.*(\d*)$","$1",$result['out']);
    if( !$number) return $name."1";
    return $name.($number+1);
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately this query will not use any index on `username`, which makes it really slow.

Comment: True. It depends on how likely a collision is. It may be better to check the original name, then use this regex if there's a collision.

Comment: Thanks Kolink,  Don't think I will go this route, but it was a solution I didn't even come close to thinking of, and always appreciate new ideas.